# How to append a key:value to a MongoDB cursor?

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

Is it possible to append a `key:value` to a MongoDB cursor?

I tried this:

```
cursor = collection.find(query,projection)
cursor['my_message'] = "value here" # trying to add key:value here
```

But it doesn't seem to work (500).

In more context, this works:

```
dbname = 'my_db'
db = connection[dbname]
collection = db.my_collection
query = {'key_1': my_var}
projection = {'key_2':1}
cursor = collection.find(query,projection)
response.content_type = 'application/json'
return dumps(cursor)
```

This doesn't:

```
dbname = 'my_db'
db = connection[dbname]
collection = db.my_collection
query = {'key_1': my_var}
projection = {'key_2':1}
cursor = collection.find(query,projection)
cursor['my_message'] = "value here" # trying to add key:value here
response.content_type = 'application/json'
return dumps(cursor)
```

**Edit:**  And just to visualise what is being returned successfully (without the appended value), it is something like:

```
[{ document_1 },{ document_2 },{ document_3 }]
```

And I expect it to look something like:

```
["my_message":"value here",{ document_1 },{ document_2 },{ document_3 }]
```

**Edit:** I tried the following as an alternative and also got a 500.

```
entries = []
cursor = collection.find(query,projection)
for entry in cursor:
    entries.append(entry)
entries['my_message'] = "value here"
response.content_type = 'application/json'
return dumps(entries)
```

Comment: Why not just split it into 2: `result = { my_message: 'value here', data: cursor }`?

Comment: This works (with commas around the keys) but it just means when iterating over the array in the frontend, instead of using `$.each(results...`, I use `$.each(results.data`.  I'd still be interested to know why I can't append to the cursor directly (which I'm assuming is a dict?).

Comment: Entries is a list, not a hash -- so it's returning a list when you call `dumps` I imagine. It wouldn't include in the list a key-value you put on the object at runtime.

Comment: I think you got lists and dicts mixed up bad. I don't understand what this experssion stands for: `["my_message":"value here",{ document_1 },{ document_2 },{ document_3 }]`. Is this a list or a dict?

Answer (score 1):

Really, [WiredPrarie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95190/wiredprairie) answered this for you right at the beginning, and everyone is saying the same thing.

We know what you want to do. You want your serialized response to be sent back with some information you want to put in and then the resultset. I also presume that you want to use these results and your other data, likely loaded into some JavaScript processing store.

I have never seen anything that didn't expect some sort of structure like:

```
{
   "result": "ok",
   "meta": [{ akey: "avalue"}, {bkey: "bvalue"}],

   "results:[              // this is your 'entries' value here
       { document_1 },
       { document_2 },
       { document_3 },
       ....
```

So what everyone is saying is **embed** your `entries` into another structure that you are going to serialize and return. By trying to push your other keys into the `entries` list you are doing it the wrong way around.